Problems with Motion Tracking and Camera Data
I'm not new to Motion Tracking but have some difficulties solving a shot.
The Specs for the Shot

Blender Version

4.2.1


Camera

DJI Air 2S
Effective Pixels: 20 MP; 2.4μm Pixel Size
FOV: 88°
35mm (Sensor) Format Equivalent: 22mm (Lens)
Sensor Size: 13.05 x 8.82mm
Recorded Image/Video Resolution: 3840 × 2160 pixels



Sources

Sensor Size: https://www.all-things-photography.com/camera-sensor-sizes-compared/#t-1636497393698

All other specs: https://www.dji.com/ch/support/product/air-2s
Tracking Situation

The Shot is a slow orbit shot around a building in a city
1'200 Frames
22 Trackers that look solid and are present over 95% of the Footage (a few end earlier or start later)

Problem

I'm unable to get a low solve error and have the suspicion, that I entered the wrong values like focal length
when I manually set keyframes (A and B), the solve error randomly changes and sometimes the error is like 600 or something. (i try to choose keyframes with about 100 frames in-between)
Almost always I get the error "Some data failed to reconstruct" in Yellow.
Lots of points do not get used for the Tracking. This is probably connected to the "Some data failed to reconstruct" message.
Points near the camera get calculated way in the distance and other that actually are in the distance get calculated near the camera (see picture)

My Questions

What Values do I have to enter in the respective fields when not working with a 35mm full frame sensor? (leave the 35 and enter the equivalent focal length?, change the sensor to the actual sensor size and take the actual focal length? Mix the two?) This is some information i was totally unable to find online!
What amount of Frame range would you recommend for the Keyframes
Why do i get the "Some data failed to reconstruct" error in Yellow even with more than 8 trackers and a lot of parallax (in my option)?
Why do a lot of my tracks not get used for tracking? I can't see about 60% of tracks in the Viewport after scene setup?



The center of the shot it the white building with the crane. I want to add the floor on top that is currently in construction:




Distribution of the Trackers:




Incorrect Calculations:
Some points that are near the camera like the ones on the roof get calculated far away (red) and the ones that are actually far away get calculated near the camera (blue)

Thanks a lot for any input!


No tracking expert, but regarding values when not using a full frame sensor: in Blender the virtual camera without depth of field gives the exact same result if you either use a full size sensor and adjusted focal length, or leave it at nominal focal length and give the real sensor size. However, crop sensors and full frame sensors in reality usually give different results, the full frame sensor usually having a shallower depth of field at least if both use the same aperture... and of course lens distortion is usually different as well.

But since aperture is no setting for motion tracking as far as I know it might be better to use the camera's real sensor size and the nominal focal length to give Blender the correct base for solving. I'm not sure how you want to "mix the two", because this will result in completely incorrect lens values.

Thank you for your comment. That is good to know! DOF is not a problem in this shot as everything is in Focus anyway.

Sure with such a wide shot DOF should not really matter. But anyway, if this was filmed with a crop sensor I would for the sake of trying to get the most accurate starting point use the actual values instead of converting it to full frame. Full frame by the way is 36 × 24 mm in digital cameras, the 35 mm comes from analog film. The default camera object in Blender uses 36 mm as well.
